# Get all revisions from CVS repository

Tags: cvs

I have set the correct CVS Root, within this root I have a repository which
contains a number of files. In particular, I am interested in the revisions of
one of the files, lets call it test.tex. Now I would like to get ALL different versions
of this file, from the repository. Is there somehow a command that I could use to do that?

Or do I need to extract them one after the other?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no cvs command to check out all revisions of one file. But with bash (or some other powerful shell) it is very easy to check them out one after the other:

```
FN="test.tex" && for REV in `cvs log $FN | grep "^revision " | cut -c10-`; do cvs co -p -r $REV $FN > "$FN-rev$REV"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

> cvs history -a -c module/test.tex

This will display all the versions of that file.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a cvs command to get all revisions of a file.

It is simple to create a script to extract all revs, using Perl for example.
If you need to get fancy, you might be able to leverage what others have done on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=cvs&mode=all)