# Checkout multiple revision of one file in CVS repository

Tags: repository, cvs

To checkout I use the following command

CVSROOT="/home/projects/stuff/" cvs co mywork

with the mywork directory I have text files as well as pictures, i.e., looks something
like this

```
- paper.tex
- pic1.jpg
- pic2.jpg
etc.
```

In particular, I am interested in checking out all the version of paper.tex over time.
Is there a way how I can check all revisions of this file out at once? Or which command
can I use to see when revision have been made to this particular file?

many thanks for your help,
Andrew

Comment: Do you want to see the log for the file or the diffs for each change?

Comment: Comments says CVS, title and tag say SVN. What is it?

Comment: sorry it is CVS, my apologies! Ideally, I would like to have the file how it looked as a whole for each revision. In other words, if there are 3 revision, than I would like to checkout 3 files that each reflect the content at the time the revision was commited

Comment: Removed `tortoisesvn` too.  I don't find `repository` to be particularly useful, but it is widely used, so I left it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724020/get-all-revisions-from-cvs-repository

Answer (score 0):

With TortoiseSVN, just right-click the file log and select *TortoiseSVN/Show Log*. That will show only the revisions where the file was modified. Then you can right-click on each revision and select *Save revision to...*

Comment: thanks, but ideally I am looking for command line for CVS. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew: Then why did you tag it `tortoisesvn` and `svn` and put `SVN` in the question title?

Answer (score 0):

To see all revision you can use the cvs log command

```
cd mywork
cvs log paper.tex
```

To get a list of all commands use:

```
cvs --help-commands
```

And to get help on a specific command use -H, eg. for the log command:

```
cvs -H log
```

Assuming you have a bash or some other powerful shell, you can check out all revision of one file over time like this:

```
FN="paper.tex" && for REV in `cvs log $FN | grep "^revision " | cut -c10-`; do cvs co -p -r $REV $FN > "$FN-rev$REV"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need mirror of the repo, then try cvssuck http://freecode.com/projects/cvssuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to display all revisions of a file:

> cvs rlog -N mywork/paper.tex

This will display all the versions and the date of each revision of the file. Once you know what revision you want you can use this command to check it out:

> cvs co -rX.Y mywork/paper.tex